# Create child window in C++ Gui Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I am new to c++ win32 programming.
I am using Visual studio 2015 edition for development.
I want to create child window from Main window and perform some task using child window.
Please guide me how to create multiple child window and perform database related functionality.
Here is my code can anyone help me why child window is not creating??

```
#include <Windows.h>
#define ITEM_MASTER         1
#define CLIENT_MASTER       2
#define QUIT_APP            3
#define ADD_ITEM            4
#define VIEW_ITEM           5

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);           // main window call back
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );          // child window call back
void AddMenu(HWND);
void CreateNewItem(HWND);
void ViewItemMaster(HWND);
void registerDialogClass(HINSTANCE);
void displayDialog(HWND );

HMENU hMenu;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {  //main function
    //MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world !!", "My first Gui", MB_OK);

    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc)) {
        return -1;
    }
    registerDialogClass(hInst);
    HWND hWnd=CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass", L"My Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 500, 500,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, ncmdshow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage((&msg), NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {  // callback

    switch (msg) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (wp) {
                case QUIT_APP:
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                    break;
                case ADD_ITEM:
                    displayDialog(hWnd);
//                  CreateNewItem(hWnd);
                    break;
                case VIEW_ITEM:
                    ViewItemMaster(hWnd);
                    break;
            }
        break;
        case WM_CREATE:
            displayDialog(hWnd);
            AddMenu(hWnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProcW(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);
    }
    return 0;
}

void AddMenu(HWND hWnd) {          // different menu
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hMstMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hItemMenu = CreateMenu();

    AppendMenu(hItemMenu, MF_STRING, ADD_ITEM, "Add Product");       // sub-sub master
    AppendMenu(hItemMenu, MF_STRING, VIEW_ITEM, "View Product");

    AppendMenu(hMstMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hItemMenu, "Product Master");   // sub master
    AppendMenu(hMstMenu, MF_STRING, CLIENT_MASTER, "Client Master");
    AppendMenu(hMstMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL,NULL);
    AppendMenu(hMstMenu, MF_STRING, QUIT_APP, "Quit");

    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hMstMenu, "Master");        //main master
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, NULL, "Transaction");
    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);
}

void CreateNewItem(HWND hWnd1) {               // some db functionality
    CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Code :", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD , 50, 50, 48, 20, hWnd1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 100, 50, 100, 20, hWnd1, NULL, NULL, NULL);                                        // some db functionality

    CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Name :", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 50, 75, 48, 20, hWnd1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 100, 75, 100, 20, hWnd1, NULL, NULL, NULL);                                // some db functionality
}

void ViewItemMaster(HWND hWnd) {             // some db functionality
    CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Rate :", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 50, 50, 48, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 100, 50, 100, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);                                      // some db functionality
}


LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {     // callback
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            DefWindowProcW(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);
    }
    return 0;
}

void registerDialogClass(HINSTANCE hInst) {               // registration for child window
    WNDCLASSW d1 = { 0 }; 
    ZeroMemory(&d1, sizeof(WNDCLASS));
    d1.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;               // initialize window class
    d1.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    d1.hInstance = hInst;
    d1.lpszClassName = L"myDialogClass";
    d1.lpfnWndProc = DialogProcedure;                  // call back procedure

    RegisterClassW(&d1);                              // register class
}

void displayDialog(HWND hWnd) {                         // creating child window
    HWND hDlg=CreateWindowW(L"myDialogClass", L"New Product", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_CHILD, 400, 400, 200, 200, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);         // create child window

    CreateNewItem(hDlg);
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve], don't just dump all of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child window proc is sabotaging the window creation process.

Modify like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {     // callback
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp); // Need to add `return` 
    }
}
```